# List of only nummbers, but I need to give it out as a list

Tags: arrays, list, console.readline

I Have to make a list of nummbers, but my conde does not work. I am new at this, that is why I would like to ask if someone could tell me how to do it

```
    [I Have to make a list of nummbers, but my conde does not work. I am new at this, that is why I would like to ask if someone could tell me how to do it.][1]
```

Comment: @"Kristine Tribere", which programming language are you using? If you're using **python** for example, you can find instructive examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify what programming language  you are using  and display the code you tried   so far

In python the list of 100 natural numbers can be created by ,

```html
numbers = [for i in range(1,101): ]
```